# iOS Swift Question: .copyBytes change in the newest build of Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift

I have some code that used to work in a previous version of XCode, but since the compiler update -- it no longer works.  It is related to the `.copyBytes` function.

Effectively I just need to `copyBytes` to a buffer.  The code is simple and looks like this:

```
var buf = [UInt8](repeating:0, count:20)

characteristic?.value?.copyBytes(to: &buf, count: 20)
```

some later code will access data in buf[0]

Since updating XCode to a new version, i get an EXC_BREAKPOINT on the copyBytes line.   I saw another question mentioned that copyBytes now takes `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` so I figure this is related.  I'm not too familiar with swift (and more familiar with 'C').  Does anyone know how to change the code above to satisfy the new version of Swift?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not still simpler `if let data = characteristic?.value { var buf = [UInt8](data) }` ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:  There was nothing wrong with the syntax of the code above.  It looks like the count field of the data structure i was trying to copy from had a count less than 20.   The previous compiler must have allowed this to happen (I.e., copied what was available without crashing? )   Changing the "count:" in copybytes to match what was available in characteristic?.value?.count fixed the crash.

Comment: Even with the previous compiler, I wonder whether the Address Sanitizer would have caught you at runtime.